# How do I prevent the script command from adding unnecessary new values to the registry so that everything else continues to work the same way?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

how do I prevent the script command from adding unnecessary new values via REG ADD to the registry so that the rest of the script code continues to work in the same way as it currently does?

Here is my current code that I managed to write:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set start=0
set end=20

for /L %%i in (%start%,1,%end%) do (
  set key=000%%i
  set key=!key:~-4!

  reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\!key!" /v DriverDesc 2>nul | findstr /i /c:"WAN Miniport" /c:"VirtualBox" /c:"Hyper-V" /c:"Microsoft Kernel" >nul && (
    echo DriverDesc zawiera niedozwoloną nazwę w kluczu !key! >NUL 2>&1
  ) || (
    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\!key!" /v DriverDesc 2>nul | findstr /i /c:"WAN Miniport" /c:"VirtualBox" /c:"Hyper-V" /c:"Microsoft Kernel" >nul || (
      reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\!key!" /v PnPCapabilities /t REG_DWORD /d 24 /f
    )
  )
)
```

It can be considered correct in 95%.

[image]

The other 5% that doesn't work is that in the place below on the screen where the numbers 0000 to 0010 are, it creates new registry entries 0011 to 0020 even though they do not exist and adds PnPCapabilities in unnecessary places.

This is how I would like the entire code script to behave correctly:

1. It looks in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} what numbers ( 0000, 0001 etc ) are currently in it.
2. Searches for "DriverDesc" in all found numbers ( 0000, 0001 etc )
   a total of 21 pieces, i.e. from 0000 and 0001 to 0020:

a) didn't find "DriverDesc" = does nothing / doesn't add PnPCapabilities

b) found "DriverDesc" = goes to point 3. below:

3. Checks what is the name in "DriverDesc" and:

a) if name in "DriverDesc" does not contain words/names etc "WAN Miniport" and "VirtualBox" and "Hyper-V" and "Microsoft Kernel" = add PnPCapabilities with value 24

[image]

b) if the name in "DriverDesc" contains anything from the words / names "WAN Miniport" and "VirtualBox" and "Hyper-V" and "Microsoft Kernel" = does nothing / does not add PnPCapabilities

[image]

Currently, the script code deals with everything, but despite operating on 0000 to 0020, i.e. it adds new digit values where they were not before and this is wrong. I would like to change that.

Will there be someone who will help me or best show what should I change so that the whole thing still works the same, but so that it does not make a mistake at the end with unnecessary addition of numbers, e.g. 0011 to 0020 that did not exist in the register before?

Comment: If anyone knows how I can optimize it to be able to shorten it or, for example, remove the beginning from setlocal enabledelayedexpansion / set start=0 / set end=20 and do it better, please advise.

Comment: IMO, the best way to optimize and improve that code is to rewrite it in PowerShell. The more logic in your script, the more batch files become cumbersome. Make the jump now.  The initial pain is well worth it (assuming there are more scripts in your future). And it's perfectly fine to continue calling Reg.exe from PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I got it right away when I added the query here, here is the correct code:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set start=0
set end=50

for /L %%i in (%start%,1,%end%) do (
  set key=000%%i
  set key=!key:~-4!
  reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\!key!" /v DriverDesc >nul 2>nul  && (
  (reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\!key!" /v DriverDesc 2>nul | findstr /i /c:"WAN Miniport" /c:"VirtualBox" /c:"Hyper-V" /c:"Microsoft Kernel" >nul) || (
    echo Add key :: !key! >NUL 2>&1
    reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\!key!" /v PnPCapabilities /t REG_DWORD /d 24 /f >NUL 2>&1
    )
  )
)
```